Can check_mode tasks be ignored in PLAY RECAP?
I am using the zypper module in check mode to test whether a certain package is installed, and base subsequent tasks on this information.
- name: check if {{ package }} is installed
  community.general.zypper:
    name: "{{ package }}"
    state: installed
  register: _package_installed
  check_mode: true
- name: change a file from {{ package }}
  lineinfile:
     ...
  when: _package_installed.changed

This works. But it's irritating that the step that is run in check_mode returns "changed" status, and is shown as such in the PLAY RECAP, even though didn't actually apply any changes on the the target system. A user who simply looks at the RECAP may erroneously assume that the play actually modified the system.
Using changed_when: false is not an option because it would cause the later when: clauses to always return false. I could resort to parsing the stdout of the zypper module, but I'd like to avoid that as it's error-prone, and the solution would be exclusive to this module.

I'm not talking about running the entire playbook in check mode (which ansible_check_mode means), just a single task in order to test a certain condition. That's actually recommended in the docs. Wrt "The problem is more making assumptions": yes, but the sofware shouldn't call for attention when there's no need. I believe the PLAY RECAP is often a used quick indicator to see if some change may need attention.

Rather than trying to install a package in check_mode, you should query package facts => https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/package_facts_module.html

@Zeitunator: thanks a lot, that works great for this specific purpose.

Someone has downvoted this question, I'd like to know why. I am sorry if the question appeared dumb. I definitely did research before posting. I just couldn't believe that there's no generic solution to the problem; I thought I was overlooking something.

In general, this isn't possible.
If a task is "changed", whether in check_mode or not, it will be displayed as such, both in the play logs and in the PLAY RECAP, unless changed_when: false is set. For some modules, it is possible to set changed_when: false, register the result, and use a module-specific return value in later conditionals (like rc for ansible.builtin.command).
For the zypper-specific problem mentioned in the question, it's possible to use package_facts instead, as pointed out in @Zeitounator's comment.
